# DataFlow uploading product images

Tags: magento, dataflow

I have several hundred products that have been added, what I'm looking to do now, is to import the product images.

In my CSV that I exported using DataFlow, I have for `image`, `small_image` and `thubmbnail` the following:

`/IMAGE_NAME.jpg` where `IMAGE_NAME` is the SKU.

When I run the DataFlow import, all I get for each image is:

`Image does not exist`.

I have uploaded the images to `/media/import and` `/media/catalog/product/import`

Has anyone seen this before? Managed to fix it?

I'm using Magento v1.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem i found, was that my images were `image.JPG` and in the CSV they were `image.jpg`.

I simply changed them to match and all is working!

Comment: there is no import file in media folder place images at  media/catalog/product/products but its not working plse suggest me

Comment: You need to import the file in Magento.